# jquery.cookie: Firefox setting cookie but Chrome isn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, cookies

I'm using jquery.cookie to store a cookie called "boom" with a value of "1234".

```
$.cookie("boom", "1234");

if($.cookie("boom") !== undefined) {
    $('.json').text("There's a cookie!");
} else {
    $('.json').text("There isn't a cookie!");
}
```

I can get it to work on firefox but not on chrome... why is that?

I'm running this locally. My uri is:

file://127.0.0.1/Users/lorenzoignacio/Desktop/Testapp/index.html.

Comment: Did you open the console (F12) and look for errors ?

Comment: No errors in the console.

Comment: I think you should set expiry in your cookie.

Comment: Changed cookie to $.cookie("boom", "1234", { expires: 365 }); and still does not work...

Comment: What version of Chrome? This works in v29: http://jsfiddle.net/Qj7rK/

Comment: Works fine here as well -> http://jsfiddle.net/J8Nw5/

Comment: You are running off of file protocol? Really? That would be the issue.

Comment: ^^^ what he said, you need an actual webserver, like wamp, to make this work !

Comment: THANKS! That works now! Why is it working on firefox though. I'm also running it off of file:///

Comment: Wether or not the browser chooses to store cookies on the file protocol seems to be up to the browser vendor, but in most cases the browser just silently fails to set cookies on a file protocol.